# Manipulate code crashes V10.1

Tags: manipulate, bugs, crash

This code is working with *Mathematica* 9, but *Mathematica* 10.1 is becomes unresponsive when I try to evaluate it.

```
Manipulate[
 co = 2.0*^8; ω = 
  2 Pi \[ScriptF] 10^6; τ = \[ScriptCapitalT] 10^-9; z0 = Z0; 
 t = ts*10^-9; 
 sol = Solve[{a + b == 
     1, (a E^(-I ω τ) + 
       b E^(I ω τ)) == (a E^(-I ω τ) - 
        b E^(I ω τ))*RL/z0}, {a, b}]; 
 Vi[t_, x_] := a E^(I ω (t - x/co)) /. sol[[1]]; 
 Vr[t_, x_] := b E^(I ω (t + x/co)) /. sol[[1]]; 
 Vx[t_, x_] := Vi[t, x] + Vr[t, x]; 
 Ix[t_, x_] := (Vi[t, x] - Vr[t, x])/z0; Z = Vx[0, 0]/Ix[0, 0] // N; 
 maxI = Max[Abs[Ix[Range[0, τ, τ/100], 0]]]; 
 maxV = Max[Abs[Vx[Range[0, τ, τ/100], 0]]]; 
 Grid[{{Plot[{Re[Vi[t, x]], Abs[Vi[t, x]], -Abs[Vi[t, x]], 
      Re[Vr[t, x]]}, {x, 0, τ co}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, τ co}, All}, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(+\)]\),\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \
\(-\)]\)"], 
    Show[ParametricPlot[{Re[Ix[γ, 0]], 
       Re[Vx[γ, 0]]}, {γ, 0, 10^-6/\[ScriptF]}, 
      AspectRatio -> Full, AxesLabel -> {"I(t)", "V(t)"}], 
     ListPlot[{{Re[Ix[t, 0]], Re[Vx[t, 0]]}}, PlotMarkers -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"o\",\nFontSize->18]\)"}]]}, {Plot[{Re[Vx[t, x]], 
      Abs[Vx[t, x]], -Abs[Vx[t, x]]}, {x, 0, τ co}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, τ co}, All}, PlotLabel -> "V(x)"], 
    Plot[{Re[Ix[t, x]], Abs[Ix[t, x]], -Abs[Ix[t, x]]}, {x, 
      0, τ co}, PlotRange -> {{0, τ co}, All}, 
     PlotLabel -> "I(x)"]}, {"Impedance Measured:", 
    Switch[Sign[Im[Z]], 1, 
     Row[{"r=", Re[Z], "Ohm", "  L=", Im[Z]/ω*10^9 // N, 
       " nH"}], -1, 
     Row[{"r=", 1/Re[1/Z], "Ohm", "  C=", Im[1/Z]/ω*10^12 // N,
        " pF"}], 0, Row[{"r=", Re[Z], "Ohm"}]]}}], {{ts, 0, 
   "Time ns"}, 0, 1000/\[ScriptF], 
  ControlType -> Animator}, Delimiter, {{\[ScriptF], 100, 
   "Frequency MHz"}}, Delimiter, {{Z0, 50, 
   "Line Impedace Ohm"}}, Delimiter, {{RL, 100, 
   "Load Impedance Ohm"}}, Delimiter, {{\[ScriptCapitalT], 0.5, 
   "Line Delay nsec"}}, ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

Comment: Hell, should we read all of this and deduce what the problem is ?! Format your code properly, provide any additional (relevant) information and, please, keep it simple -- no need to post 40 lines of code if you can illustrate it in 5.

Comment: @Sektor. Peace. No need to read it. Just run it on V10.1. First the kernel goes into a non-resposive loop and then the front-end crashes.

Comment: I tagging this with "bugs" because a _Mathematica_ crash clearly indicates a bug.

Comment: No crash for me on Windows 8.1 .  Please tell which OS you use.

Comment: It ran fine on Windows 8.1 for me until I tried to close the window, when it hung.  I had to kill it with Task Manager.  This is reproducible.

Comment: Hang under Windows 7 as well.

Comment: It also is possible to terminate this notebook under Windows 8.1 by clearing `Evaluation > Dynamic Updating Enabled`.

Comment: Hangs under linux too.

Comment: Manipulate continuously updates the argument. Add `Grid[{{RandomReal[10]}, { ...` you will see the argument is updated even when the play button is paused. In V10 I am facing a lot of troubles with `Manipulate` and it is not know how it works internally. The memory keeps building up also.

Comment: it doesn't crash for me (10.1 on Windows 7), but it does continuously update as Aloghi mentioned. I think chances are good that this will not crash if you avoid that continuous updating. That can easily be achieved by extracting the body into a function which only has the actual parameters as arguments and use that instead: `Manipulate[calculate[ts,f, Z0, RL,T],...]`. If you need this inclosed in the `Manipulate` use `SaveDefinitions`. Would you let us know if that solves your problem?

Comment: @m_goldberg I ran it @ v 10.1 and its running smooth, no kernel crashes, no nothing.

Comment: There are such problems with the code that it's hard to be sure that it is a bug. While the answer indicates it is, the nature of the bug is obscure.  I cannot reproduce it on a Mac, I'm inclined to say it's not a bug in *Mathematica*.  The continual update is due to the code.

Comment: Remove [tag:bugs]?

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer from support that it's a `Manipulate` bug.

The following code is stable(it's working on *Mathematica* 10, *Windows* 7):

```
co = 2.0*^8; ω = 
 2 Pi \[ScriptF] 10^6; τ = \[ScriptCapitalT] 10^-9; t = 
 ts*10^-9; sol = 
 Solve[{a + b == 
    1, (a E^(-I ω τ) + 
      b E^(I ω τ)) == (a E^(-I ω τ) - 
       b E^(I ω τ))*RL/Z0}, {a, b}]; 
Vi[ts_, x_, \[ScriptF]_, Z0_, RL_, \[ScriptCapitalT]_] := 
 Evaluate[(a E^(I ω (t - x/co)) /. sol[[1]])]; 
Vr[ts_, x_ , \[ScriptF]_, Z0_, RL_, \[ScriptCapitalT]_] := 
 Evaluate[(b E^(I ω (t + x/co)) /. sol[[1]])]; 
Vx[ts_, x_ , \[ScriptF]_, Z0_, RL_, \[ScriptCapitalT]_] := 
 Vi[ts, x , \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]] + 
  Vr[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]; 
Ix[ts_, x_, \[ScriptF]_, Z0_, 
  RL_, \[ScriptCapitalT]_] := (Vi[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, 
     RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]] - 
    Vr[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]])/
  Z0; xmax = \[ScriptCapitalT] 10^-9 co; tmax = 10^3/\[ScriptF];

Manipulate[
 Z = Vx[0, 0, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]/
    Ix[0, 0, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]] // N; 
 maxI = Max[
   Abs[Ix[Range[0, xmax, xmax/100], 0, \[ScriptF], Z0, 
     RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]]]; 
 maxV = Max[
   Abs[Vx[Range[0, xmax, xmax/100], 0, \[ScriptF], Z0, 
     RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]]]; 
 Grid[{{Plot[{Re[Vi[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]], 
      Abs[Vi[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]], -Abs[
        Vi[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]], 
      Re[Vr[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]]}, {x, 0, 
      xmax}, PlotRange -> {{0, xmax}, All}, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(+\)]\),\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \
\(-\)]\)"], 
    Show[ParametricPlot[{Re[
        Ix[γ, 0, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]], 
       Re[Vx[γ, 0, \[ScriptF], Z0, 
         RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]]}, {γ, 0, tmax}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Red}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
      AxesLabel -> {"I(t)", "V(t)"}], 
     ListPlot[{{Re[Ix[ts, 0, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]], 
        Re[Vx[ts, 0, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]]}}, 
      PlotMarkers -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"o\",\nFontSize->18]\)"}]]}, {Plot[{Re[
       Vx[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]], 
      Abs[Vx[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]], -Abs[
        Vx[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]]}, {x, 0, 
      xmax}, PlotRange -> {{0, xmax}, All}, PlotLabel -> "V(x)"], 
    Plot[{Re[Ix[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]], 
      Abs[Ix[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]], -Abs[
        Ix[ts, x, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]]]}, {x, 0, 
      xmax}, PlotRange -> {{0, xmax}, All}, 
     PlotLabel -> "I(x)"]}, {"Impedance Measured:", 
    Switch[Sign[Im[Z]], 1, 
     Row[{"r=", Re[Z], "Ohm", "  L=", 
       Im[Z]/(2 Pi \[ScriptF] 10^6)*10^9 // N, " nH"}], -1, 
     Row[{"r=", 1/Re[1/Z], "Ohm", "  C=", 
       Im[1/Z]/(2 Pi \[ScriptF] 10^6)*10^12 // N, " pF"}], 0, 
     Row[{"r=", Re[Z], "Ohm"}]]}}], {{ts, 0, "Time ns"}, 0, tmax, 
  ControlType -> Animator}, Delimiter, {{\[ScriptF], 100, 
   "Frequency MHz"}}, Delimiter, {{Z0, 50, 
   "Line Impedace Ohm"}}, Delimiter, {{RL, 100, 
   "Load Impedance Ohm"}}, Delimiter, {{\[ScriptCapitalT], 0.5, 
   "Line Delay nsec"}}, ControlPlacement -> Right, 
 TrackedSymbols -> {ts, \[ScriptF], Z0, RL, \[ScriptCapitalT]}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: Formatting your code is simple as pressing a button -- please, go to the help centre read more about it and use it in the future. Also Aligning your code is pretty important too.